# Path to Microsoft Word exe. File

Tags: java, windows

I am writing a simple Java program that displays the names of different programs on buttons. When you click on a button, the program will open in a separate window. To allow my program to open Microsoft Word, I need its path for my code. What is the path for Microsoft Word 2007 on Windows?

Comment: look for C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe replace office 14 with office11 ithink

Comment: the answer is "wherever the user chose to install it". its might be possible to look it up in the registry or something, but its definitely not constant

Answer (score 1):

To find the path simply right click on Microsoft Word 2007, click on properties, and then click on "Open File Location". This should open the directory containing the .exe for Microsoft Word 2007.